# Separate YEAR from other number in Python

Tags: python, datetime

given a list of string, is it possible to separate YEAR with other numbers, like in

```
ll = [700, 138.44, 5, 1862, 39.8, 30, 205.0, 30, 98.1, 180, 10, 6, 640, 29, 46.53, 45, 114, 10, 231, 2002, 2002, 176.47, 10]
```

Is there any way in Python to separate 2002 and 1862 from other numbers?

Thanks!

---

To be specific, I want to select any four digit YEAR which is obviously to human eyes. And 700 is a grey area, let's say we treat it as a normal number.

Comment: What is your criteria? It could be any 4 digit number, or a number bigger than 1800, or any number that is not a float. Please specify. 700 could also totally be a year

Comment: why are 45 & 114 not valid years?

Comment: Is the year always 4 characters long and is it always the only element that is 4 digits long? If so you can pull all the 4 digit elements out.

Comment: @HaleemurAli For a human eye, in such a list, 45 and 114 are obviously not  years. I wasn't specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to separate years from that list, assuming years are always 4 numbers and years are the only 4 number numbers in the list

```
ll = [700, 138.44, 5, 1862, 39.8, 30, 205.0, 30, 98.1, 180, 10, 6, 640, 29, 46.53, 45, 114, 10, 231, 2002, 2002, 176.47, 10]
for i in ll:
    if len(str(i)) == 4 and str(i).isalnum():
        print i
```

This will print

```
1862
2002
2002
```

You have 2002 twice in your list. You can filter duplicates out if you want.
The i'm converting the items in your list to strings so that i can check string length. I'm also making sure that all the characters are numbers to avoid printing numbers like 98.1. It ensures that numbers with decimals aren't considered since i'm checking strings lengths.

anther way to do it is to cast the list if numbers into a string once instead of twice, which would increase speed for long list

```
for i in (str(num) for num in ll):
    if len(i) == 4 and i.isalnum():
        print i
```

I'm using a generator `(str(num) for num in ll)` so that it's also memory efficient. If you want something that is easier to read you can do this.

```
ll = (str(i) for i in ll)
for i in ll:
    if len(i) == 4 and i.isalnum():
        print i
```

Comment: Really inefficient to use ```str()``` -- especially twice.

Comment: In your last example ```ll``` is still a generator. You need to call ```list()``` on the generator or use a list comp to make it a list.

Comment: You don't need to call list to run it in a for loop, try it yourself. The reason you would use a generator instead of pure list comprehension is because the impact on memory is low.  If yo want to view the item as a list then yes, you have to convert back to a list.  To use the generator, you don't.

Comment: I never said you did. Just said that it is still a generator. For loops do not convert generators to lists, they just iterate through iterables (and a generator is an iterable).

Comment: And that's what i'm doing, iterating.  I'm giving examples of different approaches. The last last one is more readable, even though the one above the last one does the same thing. It's a matter of preference.

Comment: Really don't want to argue about this, but you wrote "convert the whole list before the loop." If it is a generator, none of the items of the list are converted before the for loop, the generator function is just created. Regardless, the most efficient way to convert the values would be ```ll = map(str, ll)```.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a "year" is four digits long and is an integer:

```
def int_len(n):
    length = 0
    while n > 0:
        length += 1
        n /= 10
    return length

ll = [700, 138.44, 5, 1862, 39.8, 30, 205.0, 30, 98.1, 180, 10, 6, 640, 29, 46.53, 45, 114, 10, 231, 2002, 2002, 176.47, 10]
print [i for i in ll if type(i) == int and int_len(i) == 4]
#OUT: [1862, 2002, 2002]
```